# Conv2D vs Depthwise Conv2D calculation

Tags: c++, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to understand the similarities/differences in the calculation of 2D convolutional and 2D depthwise convolutional neural networks. (I understand the concepts).

For example, say there is an input image that is 3x3 with 3 channels (RGB) and padding of 1 and stride of 1. The filter is 2x2.

What is the output? (can disregard activation and bias)

I know that regular conv2D will have 1 3x3 output, whereas dw conv2D will have 3. Beyond that I am a little confused. Thanks

Comment: I got myself confused more now. for a dw conv2d, if input is 3x3x3, would a filter be 2x2x1? meaning there is 1 2x2 filter that is applied to all 3 input channels creating 3 output channels?

Answer (score 0):

For example, let's consider the input image shape to be `(5,5,3)`.

**Convolution Layer**:

In Conv2D, **24 Filters** of size `3*3*3` are convoluted with input `5*5*3`.

[**Conv2D**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmTsE.jpg)

***The depth of each filter in any convolution layer is going to be same as the depth of the input shape of the layer:***

```
input_shape = (1, 5, 5, 3)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(24, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(5,5,3))(x)
print(y.shape) #(1,3,3,24)
```

**Depthwise Convolution layer**:

In Depth-wise convolution, we don't specify the number of filters; we only use 1 filter:

```
z = tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(3,activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape[1:])(x)
print(z,shape) #(1,3,3,3)
```

[**SeparableConvolution**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjAw3.jpg)